# Check the number of dots present in string using golang

Tags: go

I have `cmd prompt`,In which `stdin` accept only string, but once i receive  the string need to `convert to float`. when someone mistakenly enter `"0..1" instead of 0.1,` I need check it and show error info.

```
    msg := "enter the rate eg:{0.1}"
            rate, err := RatePrompt(msg)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("something went while entering rate, please re-enter")
            }

   func RatePrompt(cmrmsg string) (price string, err error) {
      fmt.Println(" ")
      scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
      scanner.Scan()
       price := scanner.Text()
       return price, nil
            } 

    //check for string contains multiple dot

    rate, err := RatePrompt(msg)
              if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("something went while entering 
            rate, please re-enter")else{
                 ///check for string contains multiple dot
         }
   }
```

checking for multiple dot in string value, if multiple dot present throw error

Comment: I think you should use ParseFloat intead of checking for dots

Comment: strings.Count counts occurrences in a string, but you definitively should use strconv.ParseFloat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just checking for number use this instead of dot check

```
 i, err := strconv.ParseFloat(elem, 64)
    if err != nil {
        numbers = append(numbers, i)
    }
```